# CGAL - 2D Delaunay triangulation - remove is not removing

Tags: 2d, cgal, delaunay

I need to remove some points from a 2d Delaunay triangulation. I´m using remove but it is not working, the code is:

```
//---TYPEDEFS

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<K> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<K> Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb,Fb> TDS;
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_tag Itag;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,TDS,Itag> CDT;

typedef CDT::Point Point;
typedef CDT::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;
typedef CDT::Vertex_circulator Vertex_circulator;
typedef CDT::Face_handle Face_handle;

...
 
int RemovePontosDesabilitados(CDT& cdt, tysetPonto3D& SetPonDesabilitados)
{
  for (auto& RPonto : SetPonDesabilitados)
  {
    auto Face(cdt.locate(Point(RPonto.x,RPonto.y)));
    if (Face != NULL)
    {
      auto Tam = cdt.number_of_vertices();
      auto Pon = cdt.insert(Point(RPonto.x, RPonto.y));  //--- return the existing point
      cdt.remove(Pon);   
      Tam = cdt.number_of_vertices();
    }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

after the remove  Tam returns the same value.

How to correctly remove points from a 2d Delaunay triangulations?

Comment: That code should work. Probably the points in `SetPonDesabilitados` and then in `RPonto` are not exactly the same points as those in the triangulation. You should share your complete code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Irineu but even if Face does not return NULL?

Comment: Continuing with my research I found that despite the point was found in a face it was allowed to be inserted in the triangulation again, so this shouldn´t be alowed, I guess.

Comment: Small diferences on decimal places (10th place) are causing this but I think that if the point (no matter decimal places) that was found on cdt.locate()  should not be inserted again. May be cdt.insert() is failing on verify if the point exist or not. At least the search for a point on cdt.locate() is different on cdt.insert(), I gess...