# CGAL - 2D Delaunay triangulation - remove is not removing - Part 2

Tags: 2d, cgal, triangulation, delaunay

This question is continuing of the question

[CGAL - 2D Delaunay triangulation - remove is not removing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245899/cgal-2d-delaunay-triangulation-remove-is-not-removing)

Trying to solve the problem I decide to use for deletion the point returned on cdt.locate() so there will be not reason for the point do not be removed:

```
//---TYPEDEFS

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<K> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<K> Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb,Fb> TDS;
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_tag Itag;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K,TDS,Itag> CDT;

typedef CDT::Point Point;
typedef CDT::Vertex_handle Vertex_handle;
typedef CDT::Vertex_circulator Vertex_circulator;
typedef CDT::Face_handle Face_handle;

...

int RemovePontosDesabilitados(CDT& cdt, tysetPonto3D& SetPonDesabilitados)
    {
      for (auto& RPonto : SetPonDesabilitados)
      {
        Point PonRemover(RPonto.x, RPonto.y);
    
        auto Face(cdt.locate(PonRemover));
    
        if (Face != NULL)
        {
           int C(0);
           bool Achou(false);
    
           while (C < 3 && !Achou)
           {
             if((fabs(Face->vertex(C)->point().x()) - RPonto.x) < 1e-5 &&
                (fabs(Face->vertex(C)->point().y()) - RPonto.y) < 1e-5) 
             {
               Achou = true;
             }
             else
             {
               C++;
             }
           }
    
           if (Achou)
           {
             Point PonRemover(Face->vertex(C)->point().x(), Face->vertex(C)->point().y());
    
             auto Tam = cdt.number_of_vertices();
             auto PonIns = cdt.insert(PonRemover);
             Tam = cdt.number_of_vertices();
             cdt.remove(PonIns);
             Tam = cdt.number_of_vertices();
           }
        }
      }
      return 1;
    }
```

But on ***cdt.insert(PonRemover)*** the point is inserted (See that this point is **exactly** the same point found in ***cdt.locate(PonRemover)***) and on ***cdt.remove(PonIns)*** an exception is raised and the program finished.

Why is this exception being raised?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @Rabelo. I am pretty sure the exception itself carries a message that explains why it has been raised.

Comment: Hi! The problem is that I don´t know what kind of exception is being raised since I´m catchin it with elipsis (catch(...)). I´ll try to find out what kind of exception is being raised. Thank you.

Comment: You can add the line `catch(std::exception& e) { std::cerr << "ERROR: exception " << e.what() << '\n'; }` just before your `catch(...)`.

Comment: Gotcha!! (the point is part of a constrained segment) thank you.